# How to prevent cpplint to report <optional> as wrong include order?

Tags: c++, lint, cpplint

header.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <path/to/file.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

When I run cpplint.py, I get `Found C system header after C++ system header. Should be: helpers.h, c system, c++ system, other.  [build/include_order] [4]`, pointing to `<optional>`.

Is it possible to prevent `cpplint.py` from doing that, without disabling `build/include_order`?

Note: `<optional>` is c++17, which is not supported by `cpplint` afaik.

You can download my version of cpplint here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/305ac87/cpplint/cpplint.py

**Issue submitted to GitHub Cpplint:** https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/issues/138

Comment: I suggest you instead raise this as a cpplint issue. The authors are best placed to suggest workarounds if any exist.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I will do that. I wanted to post it here, since it might just be common knowledge how to solve this

Comment: Or it could have been a feature, not a bug

Comment: Would be a weird feature. Regardless, the proper place is the project itself. Good luck!

Comment: True, but you never know

Comment: I'd also check what version you're on, because https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/blob/master/cpplint.py#L485

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version, e.g. https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/cpplint/cpplint.py ?

Comment: In fact, your version has _no_ headers since C++11. Very old!

Comment: Looks like [it's the styleguide project that needs to upgrade](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/cpplint/cpplint.py) as their head is still way behind

Comment: [Five year old request to update it](https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/95)